# XML, XSL not rendering in Chrome, just showing XSL in Firefox

Tags: xml, google-chrome, firefox, xslt

I've got an XML and XSL file that will not render when opened in Chrome, and will simply display the XSL file in Firefox when loaded. Can anyone figure out where I'm missing something? I think I've already tracked down every bracket and backslash that would trip it up.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Assignment06-PresidentsXSL"?>

<LIST>
<President id="01">
    <Name>George Washington</Name>
    <Term count="2">
        <TermStart>1789</TermStart>
        <TermEnd>1797</TermEnd>
        <TermLength unit="years"> 8 </TermLength>
    </Term>
    <Party>N/A</Party>
    <HomeState>Virginia</HomeState>
</President>

<President id="02">
    <Name>John Adams</Name>
    <Term count="2">    
        <TermStart>1797</TermStart>
        <TermEnd>1801</TermEnd>
        <TermLength unit="years"> 8 </TermLength>
    </Term>
    <Party>Federalist</Party>
    <HomeState>Massachusetts</HomeState>
</President>

<President id="03">
    <Name>Thomas Jefferson</Name>
    <Term count="2">
        <TermStart>1801</TermStart>
        <TermEnd>1809</TermEnd>
        <TermLength unit="years"> 8 </TermLength>
    </Term>
    <Party>Republican-Democrat</Party>
    <HomeState>Virginia</HomeState>
</President>

<President id="07">
    <Name>Andrew Jackson</Name>
    <Term count="2">
        <TermStart>1829</TermStart>
        <TermEnd>1837</TermEnd>
        <TermLength unit="years"> 8 </TermLength>
    </Term>
    <Party>Democrat</Party>
    <HomeState>Tennesee</HomeState>
</President>

<President id="09">
    <Name>William Henry Harrison</Name>
    <Term count="1">
        <TermStart>1841</TermStart>
        <TermEnd>1841</TermEnd>
        <TermLength unit="years"> 1 </TermLength>
    </Term>
    <Party>Whig</Party>
    <HomeState>Ohio</HomeState>
</President>

<President id="15">
    <Name>Abraham Lincoln</Name>
    <Term count="2">
        <TermStart>1861</TermStart>
        <TermEnd>1865</TermEnd>
        <TermLength unit="years"> 4 </TermLength>
    </Term>
    <Party>Republican</Party>
    <HomeState>Illinois</HomeState>
</President>
</LIST>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://ww.w3.org/1999/xsl/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <HTML>
        <HEAD>
            <TITLE>
            Presidents
            </TITLE>
        </HEAD>
        <BODY>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>President</th>
                <th>Term in office</th>
                <th>Party</th>
            </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="LIST/President">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="TermStart"/> - <xsl:value-of select="TermEnd"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Party"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
        </BODY>
    </HTML>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Assignment06-PresidentsXSL"?>
> ```

Your stylesheet does not end with `.xsl`. Typcially, a web server will not send the correct response headers in that case, resulting in Chrome not recognizing it as `text/xml`. You may try to fix this by changing the filename and/or by making sure the proper headers are sent.

Even if you change the filename, and the problem persists, check the web server configuration whether it sets the mime type for this file correctly.

*Note: if you are running it from your local disk, it will not work in Chrome, and usually not in Internet Explorer (recent versions), because of security issues. Serve it from a web server instead.*

Comment: That's a pretty solid guess.

Comment: I've tried the filename with and without the extension, I've tried "text/xsl" as well as "application/xml," and it still doesn't change anything. I've also tried applying  `--allow-file-access-from-files` flags to Chrome, without any luck. Can you recommend a good XML testing program or lightweight (Windows) hosting platform?

Comment: @fluffywarthog, wait, are you saying you are only trying to do this to _test_ your XML/XSLT? Because really, browsers are the worst when it comes down to XSLT parsing. You can use any other XSLT parser, see the [xslt/info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) for a list of available parsers and development environments.

Comment: @fluffywarthog Also, consider XSLT a *server side technology*. Browser-integrated XSLT is nothing you should ever rely on in a production environment, outside of a corporate Intranet maybe, where browser choice is fixed and predictable. For any other situation, process XSLT on the server and send the result to the client.

Comment: @fluffywarthog If you don't need interactive debugging or XSLT 2.0 capabilities, [msxsl.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714) is a solid command-line XSLT processor.